# What is the benefit to use useNuxtApp() on Nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'd like to know about new Nuxt3 feature called useNuxtApp.

Official document says, to use provide, you can do like below.

```
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
nuxtApp.provide('hello', (name) => `Hello ${name}!`)

console.log(nuxtApp.$hello('name')) // Prints "Hello name!"
```

However it seems like you can also still use provide/inject.

For instance, I define the method 'hello' on parent component, then I also want to use it on child component, I can provide 'hello' for child from parent component and inject it.

You can still do same things by using provide/inject, so does anyone know what is the benefit using useNuxtApp?? And what is the difference between provide/inject and useNuxtApp except for syntax??

Comment: `useNuxtApp()` is probably just the usual `$nuxt` that was used for Nuxt2. Since you don't use `this` in a composition API context, this one seems to be an alternative approach of accessing the Nuxt instance itself. Otherwise, this may be used in composable too of course. But overall, you always had quite few approaches to achieve the same result in Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

1. useNuxtApp built-in composable of Nuxt3
2. It is used to access shared runtime context of Nuxt available in server / client side, like: Vue App Instance, Runtime Hooks, Runtime Config Variables, Internal States etc.

Example:
i) ssrContext,
ii) payload,
iii) helper methods etc.

3. Values getting by this composable will be available across all composables, components, plugins (all files of .vue)
4. In Nuxt 2, this was referred to as "Nuxt Context"
5. Let's see an example how it can be use in Nuxt Plugin and by extending the plugin  how it will give us a helper method and how we can use that helper method to get value to the rest of Nuxt Application.

say, we have a plugin in ~/plugins/my-plugin.js, where returning "provide" option as helper method.

> in ~/plugins/my-plugin.js file

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    ...
    return {
        provide: {
            hello: (msg: string) => `Hello ${msg}!`
        }
    }
    ...
})
```

> in any template (pages, components or any .vue file of the Nuxt App)

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ $hello('world') }}
    </div>
</template>
                
<script setup>
    const { $hello } = useNuxtApp()
</script>

// or

<script setup>
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
    nuxtApp.provide('hello', (name) => `Hello ${name}!`)
    console.log(nuxtApp.$hello('name')) // Prints "Hello name!"
</script setup>
```